# I need a script which will automatically trigger sendEmail function when cell value changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have written a code in which the function sendEmail sends an email which is
present in cell E9 in my google sheet which is linked to a form in my website.
As a new user enters his/her email in the form that email is reflected in cell E9 in my google sheet.
After which i have to manually run the app script to successfully send the email to the mail id
present in cell E9.
I want this to be automatic so that i don't have to run the app script manually every time a user enters
a new email.
Please suggest an app script i have little knowledge in these codes so a full executable code will be a great help. Thanks

```
 function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(9,5).getValue();
  var subject = "Checking the app script" 
  var message = "Checking the app script working from indigenious id and drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MdoADqSeudMwMruLJUU32OA5bdtyweiv/view?usp=sharing "
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need to set your function on an [installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers)

- `onEdit` triggers fire when an edit is taking place in the spreadsheet (e.g. a user enter a vlaue in a cell)
- they run your funciton automatically when an event fires the trigger
- They allow you to retrieve [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) related to the edit, e.g. the cell that has been edited and the value that has been entered - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) for available Google Sheets events for `Edit`
- Due to [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) of simple triggers, you need to use the **installable** version in order to be able to send emails
- Bind the trigger to your function as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

**Modification of your code to run on trigger (please note that due to usage of event objects this code will error if you try to to run it manually by pressing the "play" button):**

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "E9" && e.range.getSheet() == sheet1){   
    var emailAddress = e.value;
    var subject = "Checking the app script" 
    var message = "Checking the app script working from indigenious id and drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MdoADqSeudMwMruLJUU32OA5bdtyweiv/view?usp=sharing "
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  } 
}
```

This code uses the event objects `range` and `value`.

Comment: It is not running can you send me the trigger code as well. 
Thank you

Comment: You do not need a trigger code. You can install the trigger manually by clicking on `Edit-> Current Project's triggers` and follow the procedure as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)